# Self-referencing table foreign key constraint issue in SymmetricDS

Tags: azure-sql-database, open-source, symmetricds

While running SymmetricDS on Windows I am facing a foreign key constraint error, on Azure SQL Database for both slave & master, as follows.

```
    [primary-staging_prod-us-000] - AcknowledgeService - The outgoing batch 001-338 failed: 
    [FK,-900] The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_Matter_ScenarioParentID_Matter". The conflict occurred in database "DBSYNC_STAGING_PROD", table "dbo.Matter", column 'id'.
```

The table Matter has got a self-referencing foreign key constraint as follows.

```
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Matter]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Matter_ScenarioParentID_Matter] FOREIGN KEY([ScenarioParentID])
  REFERENCES [dbo].[Matter] ([ID])
```

I have modified the configuration of sym_table_reload_request as follows

```
  insert into SYM_TABLE_RELOAD_REQUEST (target_node_id, source_node_id, trigger_id, router_id, create_time,create_table,reload_select, last_update_time)
 values ('secondary-staging_prod-us-001', 'primary-staging_prod-us-000', 'TriggerAll_82', 'primary_2_secondary-staging_prod-us', GetDate(),1,' 1=1 order by ID ', GetDate());
```

But the reload_select column is not helping and the foreign key constraint gives an error while inserting records in secondary(slave) node from primary(master) node.

Here is the rest of the configuration.

```
   insert into sym_channel(channel_id, processing_order, max_batch_size, enabled, description)
   values('matter', 1, 100000, 1, 'All data from staging_prod and dbsync_staging_prod');


  insert into sym_node_group (node_group_id) values ('primary-staging_prod-us');
  insert into sym_node_group (node_group_id) values ('secondary-staging_prod-us');

  insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action) values ('primary-staging_prod-us', 'secondary-staging_prod-us', 'W');
  insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action) values ('secondary-staging_prod-us', 'primary-staging_prod-us', 'P');

  insert into sym_trigger (trigger_id,source_catalog_name,source_schema_name, source_table_name, channel_id, sync_on_insert, sync_on_update, sync_on_delete, last_update_time,create_time, sync_on_incoming_batch)
  values('TriggerAll_82', null, 'dbo', 'Matter', 'matter', 1 , 1, 1, GetDate(), GetDate(), 1);



   insert into sym_router (router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,target_catalog_name,target_schema_name,target_table_name,USE_SOURCE_CATALOG_SCHEMA,router_type,create_time,last_update_time)
   values('primary_2_secondary-staging_prod-us', 'primary-staging_prod-us', 'secondary-staging_prod-us', null, 'dbo', null, 0,'default',GetDate(), GetDate());

    insert into sym_router (router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,target_catalog_name,target_schema_name,target_table_name,USE_SOURCE_CATALOG_SCHEMA,router_type,create_time,last_update_time)
    values('secondary_2_primary-staging_prod-us', 'secondary-staging_prod-us', 'primary-staging_prod-us', null, 'dbo', null, 0,'default', GetDate(), GetDate());
```

@chenson42 after your comment, I have added the dead trigger with the following configuration on matter table.

```
insert into sym_trigger_router (trigger_id,router_id,initial_load_order,initial_load_select,last_update_time,create_time)
values('TriggerAll_82_D1','primary_2_secondary-staging_prod-us', 98,' ID in ( SELECT [ScenarioParentID] FROM dbo.[Matter] WHERE [ScenarioParentID] IS NOT NULL )',GetDate(),GetDate());


insert into sym_trigger_router (trigger_id,router_id,initial_load_order,initial_load_select,last_update_time,create_time)
values('TriggerAll_82_D2','primary_2_secondary-staging_prod-us', 99,' ID in ( SELECT [ID] FROM dbo.[Matter] WHERE [ScenarioParentID] IS NULL ) ',GetDate(),GetDate());


insert into sym_trigger_router (trigger_id,router_id,initial_load_order,last_update_time,create_time)
values('TriggerAll_82','primary_2_secondary-staging_prod-us', 100,GetDate(),GetDate());




insert into sym_trigger 
(trigger_id,source_catalog_name,source_schema_name, source_table_name, channel_id, sync_on_insert, sync_on_update, sync_on_delete, last_update_time,create_time, sync_on_incoming_batch)
values('TriggerAll_82_D1', null, 'dbo', 'Matter', 'matter', 0 , 0, 0, GetDate(), GetDate(), 0);

insert into sym_trigger 
(trigger_id,source_catalog_name,source_schema_name, source_table_name, channel_id, sync_on_insert, sync_on_update, sync_on_delete, last_update_time,create_time, sync_on_incoming_batch)
values('TriggerAll_82_D2', null, 'dbo', 'Matter', 'matter', 0 , 0, 0, GetDate(), GetDate(), 0);


insert into sym_trigger 
(trigger_id,source_catalog_name,source_schema_name, source_table_name, channel_id, sync_on_insert, sync_on_update, sync_on_delete, last_update_time,create_time, sync_on_incoming_batch)
values('TriggerAll_82', null, 'dbo', 'Matter', 'matter', 1 , 1, 1, GetDate(), GetDate(), 1);
```

I had to remove the below config because it is not picking the initial_load_select.

```
--insert into SYM_TABLE_RELOAD_REQUEST (target_node_id, source_node_id, trigger_id, router_id, create_time,create_table, last_update_time)
--     values ('secondary-staging_prod-us-001', 'primary-staging_prod-us-000', 'TriggerAll_82_D1', 'primary_2_secondary-staging_prod-us', GetDate(),1, GetDate());


--insert into SYM_TABLE_RELOAD_REQUEST (target_node_id, source_node_id, trigger_id, router_id, create_time,create_table, last_update_time)
--     values ('secondary-staging_prod-us-001', 'primary-staging_prod-us-000', 'TriggerAll_82_D2', 'primary_2_secondary-staging_prod-us', GetDate(),1, GetDate());


--insert into SYM_TABLE_RELOAD_REQUEST (target_node_id, source_node_id, trigger_id, router_id, create_time,create_table, last_update_time)
--     values ('secondary-staging_prod-us-001', 'primary-staging_prod-us-000', 'TriggerAll_82', 'primary_2_secondary-staging_prod-us', GetDate(),1, GetDate());
```

Regards

Rajat Agrawal

Comment: What version of SymmetricDS are you using?  There was a feature recently added to auto handle self-referencing keys.  https://www.symmetricds.org/issues/view.php?id=3598 was the original feature added in 3.9.9.  A bug was fixed for it in 3.9.15.  https://www.symmetricds.org/issues/view.php?id=3711

Comment: @chenson42 I am using SymmetricDS version 3.8.40. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: SymmetricDS Version 3.9.15 is not released yet. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: @chenson42 Please suggest a possible fix or workaround for this issue or do I have to wait for the new release releasing by the end of this month. Please help.

Comment: Before the feature was added the way to work around this scenario was to add multiple triggers each with their own trigger router and their own initial load select.  One trigger would have all the sync_on_* settings turned off (dead trigger).  You would specify an initial_load_select for the first trigger that would select all the parent rows and then the second trigger would load the rest of the rows.

Comment: @chenson42 Could you lead by some example configuration. I didn't understand the configuration correctly, specifically the initial_load_select config for the two triggers. Suppose I have got a table named matter with ID column as primary key & ScenarioParentID as the hierarchical key.